# Paging/Sorting is not working inside <asp:UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

i am using LinqDataSource and a gridview control and my paging/sorting works fine but when i add `<asp:UpdatePanel` than its not working, below is my .aspx page and i am not sure what i am missing...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/MAIN.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="ContPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="ContPage" %>      
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMaster" runat="server">     
    <div class="contentContainer">           
        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" OnSelecting="LinqDataSource_Selecting" 
            ContextTypeName="MyDataContextDataContext" AutoPage="true" AutoSort="true"> 
        </asp:LinqDataSource>     
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_gv1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
            <Triggers> 
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" EventName="Click" /> 
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnReset" EventName="Click" /> 
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlFilterResultBy" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
            </Triggers> 
            <ContentTemplate>              
                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    CssClass="gv" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" Width="880px" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDataBound="gvRowDataBound" PageSize="15"> 
                    <PagerSettings Visible="true" Position="Bottom" /> 
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>No  Inquiries</EmptyDataTemplate> 
                    <Columns> 
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="InquiryID" Visible="false" /> 
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="insertDate">                                
                        </asp:TemplateField> 
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression="">                               
                        </asp:TemplateField> 
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject" SortExpression="Subject"> 
                            <ItemTemplate> 
                                <a href='Edit.aspx?InqId=<%# Eval("Id") %>'> 
                                    <%# Eval("Subject")%> 
                                </a> 
                            </ItemTemplate> 
                        </asp:TemplateField> 
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Officer" SortExpression="Name"> 
                            <ItemTemplate> 
                                <asp:Label ID="lblOfficer" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>    
                            </ItemTemplate> 
                        </asp:TemplateField>                            
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="ReporterInquiryStatusDesc"> 
                            <ItemTemplate> 
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStatus" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataValueField="Id" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("StatusId")%>'>    
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0" /> 
                                </asp:DropDownList> 
                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetStatusList" TypeName="My_DAL.Status_LookupRepository" />   
                            </ItemTemplate> 
                        </asp:TemplateField> 
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression=""> 
                            <ItemTemplate> 
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSaveRowStatus" runat="server" OnClick="btn_SaveRowStatus" Text="Save" />    
                            </ItemTemplate> 
                        </asp:TemplateField> 
                    </Columns> 
                    <PagerTemplate> 
                        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 7px; line-height: 22px;"> 
                            <div style="float: left;"> 
                                <asp:ImageButton CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First" ToolTip="First Page" runat="server" ID="PagerFirstButton" />    
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="PagerPrevButton" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" ToolTip="Previous Page" runat="server"  /> 
                            </div> 
                            <div style="float: left;"> 
                                <div class="pagerNumber"> 
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="NumericPager1" CommandArgument="1" Text="1" CommandName="Page" />    
                                </div> 
                                <div class="pagerNumber"> 
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="NumericPager2" CommandArgument="2" Text="2" CommandName="Page" />    
                                </div> 
                                <div class="pagerNumber"> 
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="NumericPager3" CommandArgument="3" Text="3" CommandName="Page" />    
                                </div> 
                                <div class="pagerNumber"> 
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="NumericPager4" CommandArgument="4" Text="4" CommandName="Page" />    
                                </div> 
                                <div class="pagerNumber"> 
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="NumericPager5" CommandArgument="5" Text="5" CommandName="Page" />    
                                </div> 
                            </div> 
                            <div style="float: left;"> 
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="PagerNextButton" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" ToolTip="Next Page" runat="server" /> 
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="PagerLastButton" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last" ToolTip="Last Page" runat="server" /> 
                            </div> 
                        </div>                              
                        <div class="gridCount" runat="server" id="divGridCount"> 
                            <b>1</b> Items Found &nbsp;</div> 
                    </PagerTemplate> 
                </asp:GridView>                     
       </ContentTemplate> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel>   
  </div> 
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I see that your UpdateMode = conditional and the ChildrenAsTriggers = false for your UpdatePanel. Could it be that the Paging / Sorting postback events are not getting fired at all because of the combination of both these properties. Can you try with ChildrenAsTriggers = true and see if that makes it work just to verify if that is indeed causing the problem?

Comment: +1 Thanks and its working now and not sure how did i missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `ChildrenAsTriggers="false"` only those controls set as AsyncPostBackTrigger will cause an update of the UpdatePanel.

Why you need `ChildrenAsTriggers="false"`?

[UpdatePanel.ChildrenAsTriggers Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx)